# Removable singularity of harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

It is a well know result that if $u(z)$ is a harmonic function on an annular domain $D$ of $\mathbb{C}$ centered at the origin, then there exists a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $D$ such that
$$u(z) = \mathrm{Re}(f(z)) + C \log |z|,$$
where $C$ is a real constant. This results also applies to harmonic functions on the punctured disk $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ 0 < |z| < 1 \}$.

If additionally, we know that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} zu(z) = 0$, how do we show that $f(z)$ can be extended to an analytic function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z| < 1 \}$? That is where I am stuck. Clearly, $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} z\,\mathrm{Re}(f(z)) = 0$, by how do we proceed from there?